# Stack and Queue display conventions

Tags: java, console, stack, queue, convention

What are the conventions to display a Stack and a Queue on a console screen?
For Example, if I am in the following situation:

```
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    s.push("Hello");
    s.push("there");
```

So when I print the Stack, should `Hello` come before `there` or vice versa?

Same goes in the case of a Queue.

Keep in mind I'm working on a console screen and not an applet window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no strong conventions on how to write a stack to the screen. 
The only convention is that the last item pushed to a stack is normally called the "top" of the stack. If you are writing the elements vertically, write the most recently pushed item at the top. (It should be said that even that convention is not universal).

For a queue there isn't even that convention. Do whatever seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

[Stacks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) are LIFO(Last In, First Out) and [Queues](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) are FIFO(First In, First Out).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. But what I'd like to know is what is the convention of printing them on screen.

Comment: @iPrath, Uh..I don't believe there is a convention. I would just print them like they're stored in the respective data structure. Your question is kind-of silly.

Comment: I've been doing the same. I just wanted to ensure I haven't been doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @iPrath, In this case, there isn't a "wrong" approach, but it would be confusing for others to visualize the data structures in any other way than how they store data. :D

Comment: In that case I was doing the right thing... Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score -2):

In the case of a stack I think it is better to call `s.pop()` repeatedly and print them to the console.

Comment: This would work only if I had no more use for the data stored in the stack.

Comment: Unless the sole purpose of the stack/queue was to store stuff to print to the console, which is unlikely this would remove the data.